# How can I query nested mongoDB data in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some data in a mongoDB collection like this. Some of it may be even more nested and have more "members" entries. I want to query the data so that I get all the "artist" entries and their "members" entries.

```
{
    "songname": "random name",
    "artist": [
        {
            "name": "Band A", 
            "members": [      
                {
                    "name": "Unit A1",
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "name": "Member A1",
                            "members": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Unit A2",
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "name": "Member A2",
                            "members": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Unit A3",
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "name": "Member A3",
                            "members": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Band B",
            "members": [
                {
                    "name": "Unit A1",
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "name": "Member A1",
                            "members": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Unit A2",
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "name": "Member A2",
                            "members": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Unit A3",
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "name": "Member A3",
                            "members": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Band A",
    "members": [...]
}
{
    "name": "Unit A1",
    "members": [...]
}
{
    "name": "Member A1",
    "members": [...]
}
{
    "name": "Band B",
    "members": [...]
}
{
    "name": "Unit B1",
    "members": [...]
}
{
    "name": "Member B1",
    "members": [...]
}
```

Also, is there a way to get only a specific "artist", e.g. "Unit B1" and it's "members" in the same style?

Comment: To query a specific artist, by the `'artist.name'` field, you can use the [$ projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html) operator - this returns the first matching element. See [PyMongo find](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find#pymongo.collection.Collection.find).

Answer (score 0):

You can use your collection just as you would use a nested dictionary:

```python
collection["artist"]
```

will give you the result you were asking for.

To get the members of "Unit B1", we have to iterate over all artists:

```python
for x in collection["artist"]:
    if x["name"] == "Unit B1":
        print(x["members"])
        break
```